# Python3 - Issue when appending to list

Tags: python-3.x, list, optimization

I'm new to Python and coding in general (so the following code wont be the cleanest) but coming across the following issue that I can't seem to crack:

**Problem**

I have 2 CSVs which I'm converting to dictionaries and passing to a function one after another, in order to take the dictionary keys and append them to a list outside of the function, I'm having an issue with:

1 - When printing DataList within the function, it returns a result - when I call it from main.py, returns empty list

2 - The ultimate aim is to remove duplicates after collating data into one list (`DataList`). Within the function, when I'm appending `ClearedValues` to `DataList`, since my lists from the CSVs contain 1-6 in first & 1-7 in second, I'd expect the output (after the function has been run twice) to be:

This is the required `DataList` within function

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]
```

Instead, there is an additional `"7"` within `DataList[0]`, see output

**cleaner.py:**

```
def DictCleaner(dictionary):
    CleanedValues.clear()
    for k, v in dictionary.items():
        if v != None:
            CleanedValues.append(v)
    DataList.append(CleanedValues)
    print(f"This is the CleanedValues {CleanedValues}”)
    print(f"This is the DataList inside the function {DataList}")
```

**main.py**

```
loadCSVs("DataSet1.csv")
print(f"This is the main.py DataList list after 1 run {DataList}")
loadCSVs("DataSet2.csv")
print(f"This is the main.py DataList after the 2 runs {DataList}")
```

Where `CleanedValues` and `DataLists` are lists declared within cleaner.py outside of the function scope

& `loadCSVs()` is the function that reads the CSV, coverts to a dictionary and returns `DictCleaner()` with the new dictionary as parameter

**Output**:

> This is the `CleanedValues` `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]`
>
> This is the `DataList` inside the function `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`
>
> This is the main.py `DataList` list after 1 run `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]`
>
> This is the `CleanedValues` `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']`
>
> This is the `DataList` inside the function `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]`
>
> This is the main.py `DataList` after the 2 runs `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]`

**Expected output**:

> This is the `DataList` inside the function `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]`
>
> This is the `CleanedValues` `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']`
>
> This is the main.py `DataList` list after 1 run `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]`
>
> This is the `DataList` inside the function `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]`
>
> This is the `CleanedValues` `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']`
>
> This is the main.py `DataList` after the 2 runs `[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']]`

Any suggestions to optimize code or otherwise are greatly appreciated.

Comment: please fix the indenation of your Python code, as this is currently messed-up, and add the (abbreviated) contents of the two CSV files, too.

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak, code now indented - I can't share the content of the CSV but the data within CleanedValues would be representative e.g. DataList with 2 lists, one containing 6 values, the other containing 6 of the same value and an additional value

Comment: It's empty because you clear it: `CleanedValues.clear()`

Comment: Where do you define these variables? Scope of variables is important.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks juanpa, when I clear CleanedValues, why would that mean that DataList is also cleared?
I thought I had to CleanedValues.clear() in order to clear that variable of any data it was given during the first use of function, so I didn't end up with duplication

Comment: @PranavHosangadi CleanedValues and DataLists are lists declared within cleaner.py outside of the function's own scope but within the same file, I import cleaner.py into main and try to access the variable by print(DataList)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: Thank you @juanpa.arrivillaga I moved the CleanedValues.clear() to the top of the function and now the variable can be printed

Comment: @PranavHosangadi not really a duplicate, the OP isn't using list repetition

Comment: @RgizTk it's really not clear what you are doing. You really shouldn't be using mutable global state like that. Your functions should *take data as arguments*.

Comment: @RgizTk you keep appending **the same list object**. When you `.clear` it, it will show up empty, and since you have added it multiple times, your `DataList` will have several references to the same empty list.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ugh I swear I had one that was a duplicate for this in my list of common duplicates. :-|
Nevertheless, the reason OP sees an empty list outside the function is the same as that question.

Comment: Hi @RgizTk, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't edit the answer into the question. Instead, post an answer.

Comment: @RgizTk Why did you undo the change?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, I've solved my first issue but second issue where the additional "7" appears, as though the second run of the function is overwriting `DataSet[0]` is still present

Comment: @AnnZen apologies, I was making my own changes to show new terminal output for 2nd issue

Comment: @RgizTk I *already explained* you keep appending **the same list**. Moving the `.clear` doesn't actually fix your underlying issue. You shouldn't be using *mutable global state* to begin with.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I couldn't distinguish what your answer had provided me in terms of my problems...I have had a look at mutable global state and I have created a local list variable for CleanedValues that appends to the global DataLists and the output is as expected - thanks.

Comment: @RgizTk well, you shouldn't be appending to a list using a global variable either, but that will at least fix your underlying issue